# How to change the picture ImageView continuously?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have a ImageView inside the app .
I have 2 photos of the file drawable.
I want to photo ImagView
 Changeing every second.
Namely :
 After a second

```
  imagview.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.photo1));
```

After seconds

```
   imagview.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.photo2));
```

And this process will continue until the end

How I do it ?